# How to change password admin user activeMQ 5.9 new web console

Tags: activemq-classic

I would like to change password for "admin".
How to achieve this in 5.9 version ?

when I use the old web console I can not connect with admin/admin (http://myhost.com:8161/admin)
but I can in new web console (http://myhost.com:8161/hawtio)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 33):

Look at the file `apache-activemq-5.9.1/conf/jetty-realm.properties`.
The format is: `username: password, rolename`.  The default values are: `admin:admin,admin`.
Therefore, changing the second value will update the password.  `admin: newpassword, admin`.

Comment: and do not forget to restart activemq `sudo systemctl restart activemq`